# Get values from method in Odoo 8 API

Tags: php, api, odoo-8

I'm trying to interact with Odoo 8 API and get a list of fields. The method is called by ripcord XMLRPC library and this is the sentence:

```
$models = ripcord::client($url.'/xmlrpc/2/object');
        $models->execute_kw($dbname, $username, $password,'res.partner', 'fields_get', array(), array('attributes' => array('string', 'help', 'type')));
```

But I don't know how to get the response values...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Some of the useful document  which is related with the 
**ODOO Web Service API** in different languages 
Like Python,PHP, Ruby And Java ,

Please Click On Below Link Which is helpful for your solution.

[ODOO Web Service API Reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html)

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)