# Odoo API web service doesn't return anything

Tags: php, odoo, odoo-8

I am beginner for knowing API web service in Odoo for Android. I follow this documentation `https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html.`, so I make this code:

```
<?php
require_once('ripcord-master/ripcord.php');

$url = "http://100.100.1.148:8069"; //local IP
$db = "UAT_DISTRICT";
$username = "openpg";
$password = "serving";
$info = ripcord::client('https://demo.odoo.com/start')->start();
$common = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/common");
$common->version();

//Authenticate the credentials
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());
echo $uid; //this echo doesn't show anything, it should be 1 or 0
```

Then I try to change code like the first answer of this link [Get values from method in Odoo 8 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602740/get-values-from-method-in-odoo-8-api), I just get this error:

```
Array ( [faultCode] => 1 [faultString] => Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150723\server\.\openerp\service\wsgi_server.py", line 75, in xmlrpc_return File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150723\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 115, in dispatch_rpc File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150723\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 34, in dispatch File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150723\server\.\openerp\service\security.py", line 37, in check File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150723\server\openerp\addons\base\res\res_users.py", line 502, in check File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150723\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 241, in wrapper File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150723\server\openerp\addons\auth_crypt\auth_crypt.py", line 50, in check_credentials File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150723\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 158, in wrapper File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150723\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 234, in execute ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer = boolean LINE 1: ...T password, password_crypt FROM res_users WHERE id=false AND... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. )
```

then I googling from some site also, but I get nothing so far. Anyone can make my problem clear? Or there is better documentation/example for that, I will really appreciate.

Comment: Does this user openpg exist on the odoo server?

Comment: the openpg is exist @CZoellner

Comment: Did you check the hint in the Odoo doc?: These examples use the Ripcord library, which provides a simple XML-RPC API. Ripcord requires that XML-RPC support be enabled in your PHP installation.

Since calls are performed over HTTPS, it also requires that the OpenSSL extension be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change below kine : 
$info = ripcord::client('https://demo.odoo.com/start')->start();

Use your IP address instead of "https://demo.odoo.com"