# How to use PHP7 Ripcord library to connect odoo database?

Tags: php, xml-rpc, ripcord

Firstly, I downloaded the Ripcord files from https://github.com/poef/ripcord.git. I saved them in a folder named ripcord, located at the index directory of my PHP page.

Secondly, I enabled the OpenSSL and XMLRPC extensions for PHP7.

My code is

```
   <?php
      $url = "localhost:8061";
      $db = "test";
      $username = "admin";
      $password = "123";

      #require_once('/Ripcord/src/Ripcord/ripcord.php');
      require_once __DIR__.'/Ripcord/src/Ripcord/ripcord.php';
      $common = ripcord::client(ODOO_URL . "/xmlrpc/2/common");
      $info = ripcord::client('https://demo.odoo.com/start')->start();
      list($url, $db, $username, $password) =
      array($info['host'], $info['database'], $info['user'], 
      $info['password']);
  ?>
```

I get this error

PHP Warning:  require_once(Ripcord/src/Ripcord/ripcord.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/srija/html/logins.php on line 7
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Ripcord/src/Ripcord/ripcord.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/srija/html/logins.php on line 7

Comment: Duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440978/how-to-use-php7-ripcord-library-to-get-odoo-data

Comment: The error is different from that question and i struggle in adding a ripcord library correctly..