# Odoo XML-RPC: changing the active company?

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

My Odoo user has access to two companies but when I run code like the following (using ripcord as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440978/how-to-use-php7-ripcord-library-to-get-odoo-data)) it only shows me data for the default company:

```
$domain = [];
$domain[] = ['year', '=', '2019'];
$fields = ['account_id', 'date', 'balance2'];
$groupby = ['account_id', 'date'];
$result = $models->execute_kw($a, $b, $c, 'account.budget.report', 'read_group', [$domain, $fields, $groupby], []);
```

Adding `['company_id', '=', '31']` to the array `$domain` doesn't work.

How can I change the company I currently want to work with?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out myself. Looking at how the browser changes the company I need to do this `write` operation first:

```
$result = $models->execute_kw($a, $b, $c, 'res.users', 'write', [[75], ['company_id' => 31]]);
```

75 is my user ID.